# Naming convention for Embed Resource DLL?

Tags: .net, resources, naming-conventions, embedded-resource

I have never used an embedded resource DLL before.
I would like to start right so that I'd not have to rename DLL later on.

Suppose that, I have a Main Exe file named "Demo.exe", 
how would you name embedded resource associated with it?

Demo.Resource.dll? Resource.Demo.dll? etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be a silly question, but do you have any reason to use a separate DLL at all?

Why not just embed the resources into Demo.exe?

If you absolutely do have to have a separate resources DLL, I'd go with Demo.Resources.dll

Comment: After reading "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773718/", I thought it might have been a good idea to hide some resource.

Comment: Well, to start with you should be aware that it's not really "hiding" them much - but my point is that you can embed resources in a .exe file as easily as in a .dll.