# Windows Mobile - package mp3 with my application

Tags: windows-mobile

I am creating a Windows Mobile application for the smartphone. I want to include some mp3 files in the application resources and use them in the application. I have included these mp3 files by adding them to the solution directly but when I try and access them, I get a NullReferenceException.

Can someone please tell me how to package the mp3 files with my application or if I've done that correct what could be the reason the files are not recognized in the application?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does something like this work:

[How to Hide gif or mp3 files in my project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773718/how-to-hide-gif-or-mp3-files-in-my-project/773749#773749)

If not, can you be more specific.  A code example would be nice.  Also, are you marking the files as "embedded resource" or no?